# Low Disk Space on File System root

Tags: filesystem

I'm frequently getting below error message on elementary OS Freya.

```
Low Disk Space on File System root
```

already tried to auto remove, but it didn't work for me  (`sudo apt-get autoremove`) . are there any way to increase root capacity manually.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the output of `df`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Increasing root system is a tricky options and may result in non working OS. Backup your data before you try. If you have free space next to / partition then you can do following. You can boot your system from live USB OS (ex: Ubuntu from USB drive). After that start the gParted program. Select the "/" partition and drag scroller to new size. Click on apply. Reboot your system. This is only possible if you have free space next to "/" or if you manage to create some free space next to "/".
I am attaching a screenshot of gParted for you. [image]